# Копирование всех записей из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: python, access, база-данных, firebird, sql

Я написал программу, которая по описателю (базе данных, содержащую структуру базы данных Борей - в отдельных таблицах, содержащую список таблиц, индексов, ограничений, доменов) базы данных Борей строит её в Firebird. Затем я подключаюсь к самой базе данных Борей (Access) и хочу скопировать с помощью sql запроса содержимое таблиц базы данных Борей (Access) в таблицы созданной идентичной базы данных Firebird.

```
import pyodbc
#import kinterbasdb
import firebirdsql
import os
import json,sqlite3,sql
con = sqlite3.connect('borey.db')
sampling_tables=con.cursor()
sampling_fields=con.cursor()
sampling_constraints=con.cursor()
sampling_constraints_fields=con.cursor()
sampling_indices=con.cursor()
sampling_indices_fields=con.cursor()
sampling_indices_props=con.cursor()
sampling_fields_from_constraints=con.cursor()
js=[]

sampling_tables.execute(sql.sqltables)

for table in sampling_tables:
    tabledict=dict(inform_about_table='?', fields='?', constraints='?', indices='?')
    information_about_table_dict=dict(name=table[1], description=table[2], can_add=table[3], can_edit=table[4], can_delete=table[5])
    #print(js_information_about_table)
    tabledict['inform_about_table']=information_about_table_dict
    #print(tabledict)
    table_id=table[0]
    sampling_fields.execute(sql.sqlfields,(table_id,))
    listfields=[]
    for field in sampling_fields:
        fielddict=dict(position=field[0], name=field[1], description=field[2], datatype=field[3], char_length=field[4], can_input=field[5], can_edit=field[6], show_in_grid=field[7],
                      is_mean=field[8], autocalculated=field[9], required=field[10])
        listfields.append(fielddict)
    tabledict['fields']=listfields
    #print(tabledict)
    sampling_constraints.execute(sql.sqlconstraints,(table_id,))
    listconstraints=[]
    for constraint in sampling_constraints:
        constraintdict=dict(name=constraint[1], constrtype=constraint[2], items='?', reference=constraint[3])
        sampling_constraints_fields.execute(sql.sql_constr_det,(constraint[0],table_id))
        listitems=[]
        for constr_det in sampling_constraints_fields:
            listitems.append(constr_det[0])
        constraintdict['items']=listitems
        listconstraints.append(constraintdict)
    tabledict['constraints']=listconstraints
    #print(tabledict)
    sampling_indices.execute(sql.sqlindices,(table_id,))
    listindices=[]
    for index in sampling_indices:
        indexdict=dict(name=index[1], items='?', position='?', props='?')
        index_id=index[0]
        sampling_indices_fields.execute(sql.sql_indices_fields,(table_id,index_id))
        #sampling_indices_props.execute(sql.sql_indices_descend,(table_id,index_id, ))
        listfields=[]
        listpositions=[]
        listprops=[]
        for index_det in sampling_indices_fields:
            listfields.append(index_det[0])
            listpositions.append(index_det[1])
            fieldinindex=index_det[0]
        sampling_indices_props.execute(sql.sql_indices_descend,(table_id,index_id,fieldinindex))            
        for index_desc in sampling_indices_props:
            listprops.append(index_desc[0])
        indexdict['items']=listfields
        indexdict['position']=listpositions
        indexdict['props']=listprops
        listindices.append(indexdict)
    tabledict['indices']=listindices
    #print(tabledict)
    js.append(tabledict)
os.remove('D:/boreas.fdb')
conn=firebirdsql.create_database(host='localhost', database='D:/boreas.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
#conn=firebirdsql.connect(host='localhost',database='D:/ThirdTask/test.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
cur=conn.cursor()
for nametable in js:
    s=''
    s+='create table '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+'\n'
    s+='('+'\n'
    countfield=0
    for namefield in nametable['fields']:
        s+='   '
        if namefield['name']=='COUNT':
            s+='QUANTITY'
        else:
            if namefield['name']=='MINIMUM QUANTITY FOR ORDER REPETITION':
                s+='MINIMUM_QUANTITY'
            else:
                if namefield['name']=='PRICE ACCORDING TO THE PRICE-LIST':
                    s+='LIST_PRICE'
                else:
                    if (namefield['name'].count(' ')!=0) or (namefield['name'].count('-')!=0) or (namefield['name'].count('/')!=0):
                        s+='"'+namefield['name']+'"'
                    else:                    
                        s+=namefield['name']
        if namefield['datatype']=='FMTBCD':
            s+='   '+' INTEGER NOT NULL'
        else:
            if namefield['datatype']=='STRING': 
                s+='   '+'VARCHAR'
            else:
                if namefield['datatype']=='MEMO':
                    s+='   '+'BLOB SUB_TYPE 1'
                else:            
                    if namefield['datatype']=='LARGEINT':
                        s+='   '+'INTEGER'
                    else:
                        if namefield['datatype']=='SMALLINT':
                            s+='   '+'INTEGER'
                        else:
                            if namefield['datatype']=='CURRENCY':
                                s+='   '+'NUMERIC(18,2)'
                            else:
                                if namefield['datatype']=='BOOLEAN':
                                    s+='   '+'INTEGER'
                                else:    
                                    s+='   '+namefield['datatype']           
        if namefield['datatype']=='STRING':
            s+='('+str(namefield['char_length'])+')'
        countfield+=1
        #if countfield!=len(nametable['fields']):
        s+=','+'\n'
        #else:
            #s+='\n'
            #s+='\n'
    for nameconstraint in nametable['constraints']:
        if nameconstraint['constrtype']=='PRIMARY':
            s+='   CONSTRAINT '+nameconstraint['name']+ ' PRIMARY KEY('
            countfieldinconstr=0
            for namefield in nameconstraint['items']:
                countfieldinconstr+=1
                if countfieldinconstr!=len(nameconstraint['items']):
                        if (namefield.count(' ')!=0) or (namefield.count('-')!=0) or (namefield.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+namefield+'"'+','
                        else:
                            if namefield=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+','
                            else:    
                                s+=namefield+','
                else:
                        if (namefield.count(' ')!=0) or (namefield.count('-')!=0) or (namefield.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+namefield+'"'+')'+'\n'
                        else:
                            if namefield=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+')'+'\n'
                            else:       
                                s+=namefield+')'+'\n'
    s+=');'+'\n'
    print s
    cur.execute(s)
    #conn.commit()
    #conn.begin()
    for nameindex in nametable['indices']:
        #print 'nameidex[props] ', nameindex['props']
        s=''
        for prop in nameindex['props']:
            if prop==0:
                if (nameindex['name'].count(' ')!=0) or (nameindex['name'].count('-')!=0) or (nameindex['name'].count('/')!=0):
                    s+='create ascending index "'+nameindex['name'] + '" on '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+' ('
                else:
                    if nameindex['name']=='IDX_INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER_INVENTORY_ID':
                        s+='create ascending index ' + 'IDX_INVENTORY_ID' + ' on '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+' ('
                    else:
                        if nameindex['name']=='IDX_INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER_ORDERDETAILS':
                            s+='create ascending index ' + 'IDX_ORDERDETAILS' + ' on '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+' ('
                        else:    
                            if nameindex['name'].count('INFORMATION_ABOUT_ORDER_')!=0:
                                s+='create ascending index ' + nameindex['name'][1:4]+nameindex['name'][-len(nameindex['name'])+28:] + ' on '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+' ('
                            else:
                                s+='create ascending index '+nameindex['name'] + ' on '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+' ('
            countitem=0
            for nameitem in nameindex['items']:
                if countitem!=len(nameindex['items'])-1:
                        if (nameitem.count(' ')!=0) or (nameitem.count('-')!=0) or (nameitem.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+nameitem+'"'+', '
                        else:
                            if nameitem=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+', '
                            else:  
                                s+=nameitem+', '
                else:
                        if (nameitem.count(' ')!=0) or (nameitem.count('-')!=0) or (nameitem.count('/')!=0):
                            s+='"'+nameitem+'"'+');'+'\n'
                        else:
                            if nameitem=='COUNT':
                                s+='QUANTITY'+');'+'\n'
                            else:  
                                s+=nameitem+');'+'\n'
                countitem+=1
        print s
        cur.execute(s)
        #conn.commit()
for nametable in js:
    for nameconstraint in nametable['constraints']:
        if nameconstraint['constrtype']=='FOREIGN':
            s=''
            s+='ALTER TABLE '+nametable['inform_about_table']['name']+'\n'
            s+='  '+'ADD CONSTRAINT '+nameconstraint['name']+' FOREIGN KEY ('  
            for namefield in nameconstraint['items']:
                if (namefield.count(' ')!=0) or (namefield.count('-')!=0) or (namefield.count('/')!=0):
                    s+='"'+namefield+'")'+'\n'
                else:
                    s+=namefield+')'+'\n'
            s+='      '+'REFERENCES '+nameconstraint['reference']
            sampling_fields_from_constraints.execute(sql.sql_fields, (nameconstraint['reference'],))
            for fields in sampling_fields_from_constraints:
                field=fields[0]
                if (field.count(' ')!=0) or (field.count('-')!=0) or (field.count('/')!=0):
                    s+=' ("'+field+'");'+'\n'
                else:
                    s+=' ('+field+');'+'\n'
            print s
            cur.execute(s)
            #conn.commit()            
conn.commit()
s="""
create table CLIENTS
(
   ID   INTEGER NOT NULL,
   COMPANY   VARCHAR(50),
   "LAST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "FIRST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
   "E-MAIL ADDRESS"   VARCHAR(50),
   "JOB TITLE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "BUSINESS PHONE"    VARCHAR(25),
   "HOME PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "MOBILE PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
   "FAX NUMBER"   VARCHAR(25),
   ADDRESS   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   CITY   VARCHAR(50),
   "STATE/PROVINCE"   VARCHAR(50),
   "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"   VARCHAR(15),
   "COUNTRY/REGION"   VARCHAR(50),
   "WEB-SITE"   VARCHAR(25),
   NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
   INCLUDING   BLOB
);
"""
s1='create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_CITY on CLIENTS (CITY);'
"""db = 'D:/ThirdTask/Northwind.accdb' 
connaccess = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
DSN = ('PROVIDER = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DATA SOURCE = ' + db +  ';') 
connaccess.Open(DSN) 
rs = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset') 
strsql = "select * from deer" 
rs.Open(strsql, conn, 1, 3) 
t = rs.GetRows() 
connaccess.Close() 
"""
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\ThirdTask\Northwind.accdb')
SqlAccess=conAcc.cursor();
#print s
#cur.execute(s)
#conn.commit()
#cur.execute(s1)
#conn.commit()
#cur=con.cursor()
con.close()
conn.close()
conAcc.close();
#print "Connect succesfully"
```

Как, например, скопировать содержимое таблицы CLIENTS из Northwind.accdb в таблицу CLIENTS из boreas.fdb?

Comment: Такой листинг никто читать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы прилинковал таблицу, а потом выполнил запрос:

```
insert into T1 select * from T2
```

Comment: @msi что значит - "прилинковал таблицу"? Меня как раз интересует тот момент, как обойти проблему, что эти таблицы находятся в разных базах данных. Как обратиться к таблице другой базы?

Comment: Вы можете установить связь с таблицей из другого источника и работать с ней как с локальной. FB я не знаю, но в Access это можно сделать. Возможно, потребуется установить драйвер ODBC для FB.